# Already selected items of dropdown/combo box should reflect as selected on click over Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I  am using label for attribute for input elements in my website that will help blind users. I have Combobox/Drop down in my code to enter Date (Month/Day) format. Currently if there is only single drop down , for example Select Country, then on click on Label, already selected country is reflecting as selected, that is okay. I have used this code of Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('label').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('for');
        $('#' + id).select();
    });
});
```

But in Case of Date format as there are Child 'Label for' under Parent 'Label for' that is used for "ExpiryDate". So in this case my upper written Jquery is not working. That Jquery is working fine for Single Dropdown and for Teaxt boxes. But I want to select First child i.e. Month's already selected month should be selected. Please assist me so that I can implement it. I want to handle that when user click over Label then TextBox, Single Dropdown and Combobox/Multiple related dropdown's already entered/selected items should be shown as selected. My HTML Code is here:

```
<div class="editor-label">
  <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
  <label class="accessibleText" for="ExpirationMonth">
    <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
  </label>
  <select id="ExpirationMonth" name="ExpirationMonth" tabindex="0"><option value="">Month</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="4">Apr</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">Jun</option>
    <option value="7">Jul</option>
    <option value="8">Aug</option>
    <option value="9">Sep</option>
    <option value="10">Oct</option>
    <option value="11">Nov</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
  </select>

  <label class="accessibleText" for="ExpirationDay">
    <label for="ExpiryDate">*Expiration Date</label>
  </label>
  <select id="ExpirationDay" name="ExpirationDay" tabindex="0"><option value="">Day</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
$(function () {
    $('label').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('for');
        $('#' + id).focus();
    });
});
```

But this is already done by the browser right?

Comment: But its working only for textboxes and simple Combobox. But what I want is  1st option should be automatically selected on clicking on label text if one label is connected with more than 1 form fields.

Comment: You cannot have nested `label`.

Comment: Is there any alternative that I can select first child element on click over label?

Comment: @user4956321 Could you please explain, what exactly you wanna do with your code?